# Extract file names from git pull output

Tags: perl, git, bash

I am creating a script that will pull down the latest master branch of code, and check to see if any of the file names are SQL. After I have determined the filename, I am going to source the stored procedures. Currently I have it pulling the code and readying the output line by line, however my grep command doesn't seem to be able to find the sql filename. This is what I have

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pull all of the latest code for the master branch, and set the commit log to 
# a variable
commit_log=$(git pull origin master --quiet)

#read the commit log line by line
echo $commit_log | while read line
do
    if [ `echo "$line" | grep -E "(\.sql)$"` ]; then
        echo "SQL"
    fi      
    echo "LINE:" $line 
done
```

I am not stuck on bash, I could also do this in perl.

Comment: After pulling, run `git diff --name-only HEAD^1..HEAD` and use the filenames from there.

Comment: @ScallioXTX I would add that you should check your current version before pulling and then showing the diff between your version and the new head. When pulling you can receive many commits in one bunch... or none. The task is not that trivial. You could be on a revision that is not even part of the final history if you merge. git pull --rebase could also be a problem.

Comment: In your construct the brackets and the backticks are wrong. Just leave them out.

Comment: @Lynch good point, I was going a bit too fast there. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a pull the new state is stored in HEAD and the old one in HEAD@{1}.
You can find the changed files between both with `git diff --name-only`.
A small perl one-liner seems to be the easiest way to check the file names:

```
git pull
git diff --name-only HEAD@{1} | perl -wpe 'print "SQL:" if /\.sql$/'
```